# NDSolve doesn't let me evaluate function at an arbitrary point

Tags: differential-equations

I have a piece of code that looks like this

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == - 2 x[t] + x[t]^2, x[0] == 1}, {x[t]}, {t, to, to + 0.01}];
```

And if I plot it it looks fine

```
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 0.01}]
```

But if I try something like

```
x[0.005] /. sol
```

It just returns `{x[0.005]}`
Why? is there a way to evaluate a solution from NDSolve at an arbitrary value without having to plot the whole thing?

Comment: Try `x[t] /. sol /.t->.005`

Comment: ...  or change `{x[t]}` in the second argument of `Solve` to `x`.